# Invalid Session ID error when attempting to link Flask and Selenium Together

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask

So for a project of mine, I'm trying to use a flask server to initiate logins and interactions with a different website. Everything was going pretty fine, all of my selenium framework is up to date and all of my functions associated with interactions and logins work on their own.

I have all my selenium stuff in its own class and this is what it does on init:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.logged_in = False
        self.service = Service(executable_path=r"./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        #self.options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.service, options=self.options)
        self.driver.get("url")
```

On my other side, where my flask and main is, I create a class to hold an instance of my selenium stuff in a fashion like so:

`scheduler = RoomScheduler(booker=RoomBooker())`

then separate I have scheduler manage the results for the flask routes

```
    @app.route('/task_enqueue', methods=['POST'])
    def enqueue_task():
        return scheduler.valid_task()
```

will take html form inputs and pass them to the selenium class function  to do a login, then after it is done I have it redirect to a completion page.

My main is as follows:

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, keyboard_interrupt_handler)
        logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.INFO,filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %           (levelname)s - %(message)s')
        logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        scheduler.process_file()
        host = host  
        port = 5000  
        url = f'http://{host}:{port}/'
        webbrowser.open(url) 
        app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=False, use_reloader=False)
```

When I start it up, it properly opens the webdriver and flask in my browser, but when I go to submit the form and the selenium class tries to interact with the webdriver, which mind you it has direct access to, it can't, giving me an invalid session ID error.

[As you can see in logs, it starts the flask server, and upon trying to schedule a task, it says invalid session ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmakW.png)

I thought it was a problem with my selenium class, but when testing it on its own, there are no issues at all, and works as intended. So the problem only occurs when I try to give flask the reins to send commands to it.

- I've made sure my drivers and binaries are up to date because that can cause invalid session ID errors
- Tried using Gunicorn to avoid the issue, nope didn't work
- Tried manually increasing the max number of connections via http = urllib3.PoolManager(maxsize=10) (this was I believe a suggestion from some other stack overflow post)
  -Thought that the experimental option of self.options.add_experimental_option("detach", True), was causing it, it wasn't
  -I've ensured my flask and my webdriver aren't restarting randomly or closing early

Overall, I'm stumped on how to handle this properly. I'm certain I'm doing everything sequentially without concurrency in terms of commands and requests. The only thing that is happening at the same time is that Flask and my webdriver are both running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so my problem was solved not through anything relating to connection pools or flask itself, but rather how I interacted with redirecting and my assumptions about a specific mechanic relating to script I used along with my HTML.

```
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() { 
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/shutdown', 
             async: true,  
        });
     });
```

I assumed that 'beforeunload' would only trigger if the user exited the flask tab in which I opened for them using  webbrowser.open(x), not on redirects. As a result of this, my shutdown function was always running right before my scheduler.valid_task() because of the flask routing I had in place. In other words, I was getting the session ID error because I was attempting to communicate with the webdriver that was already closed/shutdown.

"I've ensured my flask and my webdriver aren't restarting randomly or closing early"

Nope, I guess I didn't. Welp solved now.